Should we seed some questions about the LEGO movie?
I don't mean questions about the movie itself, but how to build items from the film, or parts used, etc.  The sort of things that drive traffic.
Yes? No? Maybe? Crickets?

By all means. I guess you'd want to be careful you didn't ask about items that are included in the official sets though
